# SearchView (not in toolBar) how show drop down list for full-length of screen

Tags: android, searchview

In my fragment (not in ToolBar) I has SearchView component.
Here fragment's layout:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:defaultQueryHint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my suggestion's item layout in xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_min_height_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catalogImageView"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/suggestion_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="@dimen/standard_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalogNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test text View Test text "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/catalogImageView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/catalogNameTextView" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here java code in my fragment in xml file:

```
searchV = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
SearchManager searchMng = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchV.setSearchableInfo(searchMng.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchV.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter(ctx);
```

And here result:

[image: SearchView drop down]

But I need to remove gap. I want drop down to show for full lenght.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this first calculate the size of the screen

```
//make one global variable for popup width
int suggestionPopUpWidth;

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
suggestionPopUpWidth = size.x;


//Use this method for setting width
private void setDropdownWidthHeight() {
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete mSearchSrcTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
mSearchSrcTextView.setDropDownWidth((int) (suggestionPopUpWidth * 0.9));
}
```

call this method setDropdownWidthHeight after setting suggestion adapter